# Libraries used in Android

Tags: android, cross-compiling, android-source, dalvik, bionic

I've downloaded the source from https://android.googlesource.com and I now want know if I can compile the libraries(bionic) and Dalvik VM using a cross compiler? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

All the dependency is given on http://source.android.com/source/download.html as follows:

> $ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid
>   partner"
>  $ sudo add-apt-repository "deb-src
>   http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner"
>  $ sudo apt-get
>   update
>  $ sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
>  $ sudo
>   update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun
>  $ sudo apt-get install
>   git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential zip curl zlib1g-dev
>   gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 lib32ncurses5-dev ia32-libs
>   x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32readline5-dev lib32z-dev

Comment: to be more specific, I mean the system libraries like bionic, webkit, sql lite, etc..if i do a make to get the emulator running, I get three files(system.img, ramdisk.img and data.img). system.img has the libraries and default system packages. I want to compile the libraries so that I get a binary like the one present in system.img

Comment: I think that all libs are there in the android source repo. <BR> listed on http://android.git.kernel.org/

Comment: yes I've got them using repo. How do I compile them separately using a cross compiler?